# What is the meaning of this sentence: "What they lack in size, they certainly make up for in importance"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I encounter this sentence in the bellow paragraph while reading the article here: https://www.openaccessgovernment.org/artificial-intelligence-hr-and-recruitment/64358/

> Human resources is arguably one of the most important departments in any reasonably sized organisation.
>
> "What they lack in size, they certainly make up for in importance".

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

'Human resources' here means "[The department of a business or organization that deals with the hiring, administration, and training of staff](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/human_resources)".

So the sentence means this:

> The department of human resources in a reasonably sized organization may be smaller in size than other departments, but it's more important than other departments.

Structurally, *what they lack in size* is object of the preposition *for*, which can be marked with a pronoun *it*:

> What they lack in size, they certainly make up for **it** in importance.

Comment: Thanks! it becomes clear to me now.